# create dynamic page on plug-in activation

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I'm learning to developing plug-ins for Wordpress. After activating my plug-in it creates a new page with the following code:

```
function add_page(){
    global $wpdb;
    $page = array(
        'post_title' => 'test',
        'post_content' => 'HERE I WANT PHP CODE',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type' => 'page',
    );  

    // insert post into the database
    wp_insert_post( $page );
}
```

What is the cleanest and proper way of adding php to 'post_content'?
I want to make a user-overview page by querying the database.

Comment: What's the purpose of the PHP code? Putting PHP-code in the database is generally a really bad idea and can usually be solved in other ways. Other than that, PHP-code is just text until it's parsed so putting it in the db is as simple as adding any text string.

Comment: The page that I'm creating needs to contain php code to query the database. It's not smart to save this in de database but for now I don't have any other options. What do you suggest?

Comment: Edit to question to give more details about which datas must show this page.

Comment: @mmm need more details? What about using shortcodes for representing php code?

Comment: You just answered your own question. Create a short code for it instead.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @MagnusEriksson